# When raspberry Pi motor controling program ended, motor still work

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I am controlling motor with raspberry pi, using wiringPi.
I made my code, and implemented. It worked.
But when I exit the code, motor was still working.
How can I stop this?

```
while(1){
            digitalWrite(EN1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
            delay(10000);

            digitalWrite(EN1, LOW);
            delay(5000);

            digitalWrite(EN1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
            delay(10000);

            digitalWrite(EN1, LOW);
            delay(5000);
    }
```

Comment: do you stop your motors before exiting ? Can you edit your post and put your code ?

Comment: I didn't. But if I exit, I think ports will be stop to  sending 5v or 0v.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your

```
while (1)
```

I understand you stop with a signal, like Ctrl-C. You should use signal handler to handle the stop and when you catch the signal, you should stop the motors with

```
digitalWrite(EN1, LOW);
```

Comment: Thank you! And when I use softPwmWrite, I can stop with Ctrl-C even if I use while(1).